# Executing function with param(s) in Google Guice

Tags: java, guice

I have the following module to convert to Guice:

```
Serializer serializer = new SerializerBinaryImpl("testdong");
Dong dong = new DongImplementation();
View view = new TextView(dong);
dong.setSerializer(serializer);
view.setDong(dong);
```

Here what I have so far:

```
bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Name.class).toInstance("testdong"); 
bind(Serializer.class).to(SerializerBinaryImpl.class);
bind(Dong.class).to(DongImplementation.class);
bind(View.class).to(TextView.class);

//dong.setSerializer(serializer); - Not sure how to do      
//view.setDong(dong); - Not sure how to do
```

Simple solution is best solution. This is just a simple project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to annotate the methods with `@Inject` (This is called [method/property injection](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections)) :

```
@Inject
public void setSerializer(Serializer serializer) {
    this.serializer = serializer;
}
```

...

```
@Inject
public void setDong(Dong dong) {
    this.dong = dong;
}
```

This is no more configuration to do in your module.  Guice will automaticaly inject :

- `DongImplementation` in your `TextView`
- `SerializerBinaryImpl` in the `DongImplementation`

Comment: your answer is correct but i found out that i had to set the dong as singleton then it works fine.

Comment: Yes if you want to use the same dong instance everywhere.